# Snapping at Blender

Tags: mesh

I am trying to snap three circles as follows, I am using snapping and auto merge to assure they are connected, however, I couldn't place the third circle correctly, in other terms it is not allowed when snap is activated
[image]

I want them to be in this following position

[image]

**EDIT**
Is this correct?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is select the *Snapping > Target > Active* option, it means that the active vertex (the last selected vertex) will be the one that will snap. Much more convenient than *Closest* in that case.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for saving my life :)